# How can I access to internet in iPhone 4 with USB or other way through my mac book pro?

Tags: iphone, internet

I have a iPhone 4 and Mac book pro. I am accessing internet in Macbook through dsl modem lan. But I don't know how to access internet in iPhone.

My specific question is there any way to access internet through USB or any other way with through my mac book pro????

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by sharing your MacBook Pro's internet connection - typically called an ad-hoc network.

You will need to connect your USB aircard, and then open System Preferences > Sharing > Internet Sharing. ([From this Apple Forum post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4473401?start=0&tstart=0)) Select USB from the drop down menu next to "Share your connection from:". Then select the "Wifi" from the checkboxes below. Check the Internet Sharing option to the left, then join it with your iPhone.

[Here is an Apple KB support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10666) that you may find helpful in setting up an ad-hoc network. While you are using USB the steps [in this OSX Daily article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/05/enable-internet-sharing-mac-os-x/) should be very similar to your situation.

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to vote up your post.

Comment: @BVR, No problem. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Without a Jailbreak you can be sure that you can't connect to the internet trough USB. iOS devices need either Celular network or Wifi.